# Shared counter using combining tree deadlock issue

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, counter

I am working on a shared counter increment application using combining tree concept. My goal is to make this application work on 2^n number of cores such as 4, 8, 16, 32, etc. This algorithm might err on any thread failure. The assumption is that there would be no thread failure or very slow threads.

- Two threads compete at leaf nodes and the latter one arriving goes up the tree.
- The first one that arrives waits until the second one goes up the hierarchy and comes down with the correct return value.
- The second thread wakes the first thread up
- Each thread gets the correct fetchAndAdd value

But this algorithm sometimes gets locked inside while (nodes[index].isActive == 1) or while(nodes[index].waiting == 1) loop. I don't see any possibility of a deadlock because only two threads are competing at each node. Could you guys enlighten me on this problem??

```
int increment(int threadId, int index, int value) {
    int lastValue = __sync_fetch_and_add(&nodes[index].firstValue, value);
    if (index == 0) return lastValue;
    while (nodes[index].isActive == 1) {
    }
    if (lastValue == 0) {
        while(nodes[index].waiting == 1) {
        }
        nodes[index].waiting = 1;
        nodes[lindex].isActive = 0;
    } else {
        nodes[index].isActive = 1;
        nodes[index].result = increment(threadId, (index - 1)/2, nodes[index].firstValue);
            nodes[index].firstValue = 0;
            nodes[index].waiting = 0;
    }
    return nodes[index].result + lastValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that will work on 1 core. You infinitely loop on isActive because you can't set isActive to 0 unless it is 0.

I'm not sure if you're code has a mechanism to stop this but, Here's my best crack at it Here are the threads that run and cause problems:

ex)

```
thread1                         thread 2
nodes[10].isActive = 1
                                //next run on index 10
                                while (nodes[index].isActive == 1) {//here is the deadlock}
```

It's hard to understand exactly what's going on here/ what you're trying to do but I would recommend that somehow you need to be able to deactivate nodes[index].isActive. You may want to set it to 0 at the end of the function

Comment: You are right that this doesn't work on 1 core. One of the not mentioned assumptions is that there will be 2^n number of cores.

Comment: Right. N=0 corresponds to 1 core. Also I'm pretty sure if it won't run on 1-core that it can't run on any multiple of 1. That was the original intent of the comment